# Access vba sql query with date in format dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I searched how to solve my issue in many post but can't find an asnwer.

I need to perform a select in sql where one of the criteria is a date that is between other two dates.

My problem is that my date field in the database is a text area and i need a date to work with

If i run my sql sentence with the date writen it works, but there's a problem when i use variables, here i show the code used.

Thanks in advance

```
 Dim fechaM As Date
 Dim fechaAnt As String
 Dim fechaPost As String

fechaM = Format(CDate(Nz(rs!fecha_m)), "dd/mm/yyyy")
fechaAnt = Format(CDate(Nz(rs!fecha_m)) - 7, "dd/mm/yyyy")
fechaPost = Format(CDate(Nz(rs!fecha_m)) + 7, "dd/mm/yyyy")

Set rsAguas = Db.OpenRecordset("SELECT table_user.nombre FROM table_user INNER JOIN M_A ON " & _
                                   "table_user.localizacion = M_A.localizacion WHERE " & _
                                   " fechaM " Between " & fechaAnt & " AND " & fechaPost & " " & _
                                   " AND ((M_A.estado)=1)")
```

When i run this code i don't get error, but it doesn't retrieve data

Comment: why would you have a date field in a db as a varchar? It makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bast way to deal with International Dates in Access is to use Allen browne SQLDate Function [Allen browne site](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html) . 
the function

```
Function SQLDate(varDate As Variant) As String
'Purpose:    Return a delimited string in the date format used natively by JET SQL.
'Argument:   A date/time value.
'Note:       Returns just the date format if the argument has no time component,
'                or a date/time format if it does.
'Author:     Allen Browne. allen@allenbrowne.com, June 2006.
If IsDate(varDate) Then
    If DateValue(varDate) = varDate Then
        SQLDate = Format$(varDate, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")
    Else
        SQLDate = Format$(varDate, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy hh\:nn\:ss\#")
    End If
End If
```

End Function

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt `DateValue` and `DateAdd` functions:

```
WHERE 
    (M_A.estado = 1) AND
    DateValue(fechaM) Between DateAdd("d", -7, DateValue(fechaM)) AND DateAdd("d", 7, DateValue(fechaM))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing it a little. Try:

```vb
Dim fechaM As Date
Dim fechaAnt As String
Dim fechaPost As String

fechaM = Nz(CVDate(rs!fecha_m.Value), Date)
fechaAnt = Format(DateAdd("d", -7, fechaM), "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
fechaPost = Format(DateAdd("d", 7, fechaM), "yyyy\/mm\/dd")

Set rsAguas = Db.OpenRecordset("SELECT table_user.nombre FROM table_user INNER JOIN M_A ON " & _
                                   "table_user.localizacion = M_A.localizacion WHERE " & _
                                   "(fechaMfield Between #" & fechaAnt & "# AND #" & fechaPost & "#) " & _
                                   "AND (M_A.estado = 1)")
```

Here, *fechaMfield* is the name of your date field of the table.

If *fechaMfield* is text, use `DateValue([fechaMfield])` in the query.

Comment: If you don't provide any info, no one can help.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't find info to provide because i didn't get an error, only the recordset return nothing like what i did.

Please check xShen answer because that works. The problem was the query didn't like the calculated date -7 and +7 days but if you insert those fields in a temporary table and the read and convert it by using the funcition from Allen Browne the query works.

Thank you again for your effort.